# Add Overlay Color With Centered Text

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am trying to achieve following:

Add overlay color to Shortcode element in WP with centered Text.

When user hovers over this overlay color and text must be hidden.

I tried lots of variantsannd this one nearly works, but it's not showing text:

```css
#image-map-pro-2380 > div > div.imp-ui{
        max-width: 100%;
        -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-radius: 3px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        outline: none;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        background: #000;
        color: #FFF;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 0.7;
        content: "OUT OF STOCK";
}
```

Also another problem is that when using

```
:hover {
   display:none;
}
```

overlay color starts blinking not hiding.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**I don't know, if this is what you want but let me show u this code it doesnt make the text disappear**

```html
   

 

<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    

    #overlay {
      position: fixed;
      display: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
      z-index: 2;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="overlay" onclick="off()"></div>

    <div style="padding:20px">
      <h2>Overlay</h2>
      <p>Add an overlay effect to the page content (100% width and height with a black background color with 50% opacity).</p>
      <button onclick="on()" id="btn" >Turn on overlay effect</button>
    </div>

    <script>
    function on() {
      document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
    }

    function off() {
      document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "none";
    }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Try these***

```
:hover {
   display:none;
}
:focus {
   display:none;
}
```

***JAVASCRIPT***

```
document.getElementById("").disabled = true;
```

Comment: tried it already not works. but the main problem is text is not showing on overlay color

Comment: Try Use Javascript

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_pushbutton_disabled.asp

Comment: Page I am using this code is: https://chsa.upspot.ge/projects/

Code which I provided above is the main one and for hover focus I am using this:


#image-map-pro-2380 > div > div.imp-ui:hover{
    display: none;}
#image-map-pro-2380 > div > div.imp-ui:focus{
    display: none;}

Comment: Also I have sent something you might wanna look at

Comment: I dont think there no fix

Comment: The problem is I want to achieve same effect seen here: https://binadari.com/site/projects/home_v2/ge

You can see that there is a overlay with text and color on elements and when you hover over it dissapears I want to achieve exact same thing. Without any luck...

Comment: Then Copy The Code

Comment: wasn't able to do that, that's why asking for help

Comment: what code? this site: binadari.com/site/projects/home_v2/ge is not mine and can't copy their code..

Comment: Why don't you remove the overlay because that is what is making the problem

Comment: But I want an overlay and text over it

Comment: It's the only way

Comment: Or maybe you didnt tell the CSS were the mouse is on the button

Comment: Just search up hide overlay on button hover

Comment: Also Your Return Back Is It Suppose To Use window.history.back();